# Turn this AS3 into an array and work with it

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I turn this basic function method into an Array and call to easily. Pretty much I am just comparing if objects have become false and then do something...but this just seems like a lot of code for something so easy. any ideas?

```
    var b:Boolean = true;
        var i:Boolean = true;
        var t:Boolean = true;
        var a:Boolean = true;
        var m:Boolean = true;
        var ii:Boolean = true;
        var n:Boolean = true;
        var e:Boolean = true;
        var s:Boolean = true;

        level5_mc.let_b_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitB);
        level5_mc.let_i_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitI);
        level5_mc.let_t_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitT);
        level5_mc.let_a_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitA);
        level5_mc.let_m_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitM);
        level5_mc.let_ii_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitII);
        level5_mc.let_n_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitN);
        level5_mc.let_e_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitE);
        level5_mc.let_s_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hitS);


        function hitB(event:MouseEvent){
            b=false;
            trace("good");
              level5_mc.removeChild(level5_mc.let_b_mc);  
        }

        function hitI(event:MouseEvent){
            if (b==false){
                i=false;
                level5_mc.removeChild(level5_mc.let_i_mc);  
            }
            else {
                //decrease timer
                i=true;
            }
        }

        function hitT(event:MouseEvent){
            if (b==false && i==false){
                t=false;
                level5_mc.removeChild(level5_mc.let_t_mc);  
            }
            else {
                //decrease timer
                i=true;
            }
        }
```

and so forth... edited below

```
 var b=level5_mc.let_b_mc;
                    var i=level5_mc.let_i_mc;
                    var t=level5_mc.let_b_mc;

                var movieClips:Array = [b,i,t];
                var movieClipFlags:Object = {
                    b:[],
                    i:[b],
                    t:[b,i]
                };

                for each(var mc:MovieClip in movieClips) {
                   mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,movieClipHit);
                }

                function movieClipHit(e:MouseEvent) {
                   var mc:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
                   if(readyToRemove(mc))
                      level5_mc.removeChild(mc);
                   else
                      trace("Can't remove yet.");
                }

                function readyToRemove(mc:MovieClip):Boolean {
                   for each(var mc:MovieClip in movieClipFlags[mc]) {
                       //if it has parent, it isn't removed yet.
                       if(mc.parent)
                         return false;
                   }
                   return true;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following should give you some ideas. I haven't tested the code you migt need to make some adjustments depending on your needs.

```
//put other movies clips in this array too.
var movieClips:Array = [level5_mc.let_b_mc,level5_mc.let_i_mc]; 


var movieClipFlags:Object = {
   level5_mc.let_b_mc:[],
   level5_mc.let_i_mc:[level5_mc.let_b_mc],
   level5_mc.let_t_mc:[level5_mc.let_b_mc,level5_mc.let_i_mc]
   //put other movie clips here too with the movie clips that need to be removed in the array
};

foreach(var mc:MovieClip in movieClips) {
   mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,movieClipHit);
}


private function movieClipHit(e:MouseEvent) {
   var mc:MovieClip = e.target as MovieClip;
   if(readyToRemove(mc))
      level5_mc.removeChild(mc);
   else
      trace("Can't remove yet.");
}

private function readyToRemove(mc:MovieClip):Boolean {

   foreach(var mc:MovieClip in movieClipFlags[mc]) {
       //if it has parent, it isn't removed yet.
       if(mc.parent)
         return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I keep getting syntax errors "expecting identifier before dot, and expecting identifier before rightbrace on the lines of these
    level5_mc.let_b_mc:[],
    level5_mc.let_i_mc:[level5_mc.let_b_mc],
    level5_mc.let_t_mc:[level5_mc.let_b_mc,level5_mc.let_i_mc],
in the object section. I like your method, just having a problem with syntax, thanks a bunch, if you can get around to it, helping me out with these errors would be awesome. Either way, your logic is worthy, thanks man

Comment: Removed the code that was causing the errors, you still need to put all your movieclips into that array `movieClips` and into `movieClipFlags`.

Comment: i fixed all the errors (see above), i made the movieclips variables like this  var b=level5_mc.let_b_mc; and used b and so forth in the array and in the object, but now I get this...ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
 at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
 at MethodInfo-271()

Comment: That happens when you try to remove a movieclip from a container that is not the parent of the movieclip, make sure you are removing from the correct parent.

Comment: when i trace the array movieClips i get let_b_mc_50, let_i_mc_52, let_t_mc_54 and so forth. what is that added number. and if I replace the (mc) with (b) it works for b, so something must be wrong with my (mc). anyways, I think I will leave it as I had it. This is mind boggling for me lol